# How can I set fixed position Background image in jquery mobile for iPhone app using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, background-image, fixed

I am doing a iPhone app using Phonegap & also using jquery mobile. I want to set background image for data-role=page div. In this height of page is equal to screen & hence background is set to size of screen. But the page content length is much greater than screen & hence gray background is seen after image completes. 
  My question is whether there is a way so that we can keep the background image fixed & scroll or move only content of page & not background image.
  Just to mention I have tried [full size background jquery pluggin](http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/). Its working on Android but not on iOS.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so what I did instead was to create a fixed element within the body element of the page.
So it would look like

```
<body>
   <div id="background"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

And for the CSS I stated the following:

```
    #background {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(images/bg-retina.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

And this did the trick for me. Hopefully it helps (someone out there :P)

Answer (score 4):

You looking for [css](/questions/tagged/css) [`background-attachment`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-attachment) property.

```
div[data-role="page"]{
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**Update:**
`background-attachment:fixed` is supported from **iOS 5**, if you using older version of iOS you may consider usage of [`iScroll`](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

Comment: It works starting from iOS5, if you using older version of iOS WebKit version used by Safari doesn't support `background-attachment:fixed`

Comment: JuicyScripter has explained that fixed position only works on iOS5+ and that only using a library like iScroll will give the same effect on iOS4 and below.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your background image to the jQuery page:

```
.ui-page { background-image:url(../ios/sample~ipad.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;
background-attachment:scroll; background-size:100% 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 .ui-mobile
 .ui-page-active{

 display:block;
 overflow:visible;
 overflow-x:hidden;

 }
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, this work for me.

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: url(../Images/loginBackground.jpg) 0 0  fixed !important;
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
   <div id="background"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

css:

```
#background {
    background-image: url("/images/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-position: 0 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #background {
        background-attachment: initial !important;
    }
}
```

The problem is that iOS mobile devices have errors rendering simultaneously `background-size:cover;` and `background-attachment:fixed;` so you have to fix it by `@media`