# Fixed Position Background on iOS

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile, fixed

I have a website that has a full-image fixed background that the content "floats" above. It works fine in desktop browsers, but the fixed background ends up scrolling on iPads and other tablets. This seems to be a common issue, but then I ran across this website, which seems to have a fixed background even on iPad's.

http://confitdemo.wordpress.com/

Any clue how they are pulling that off? I tried:

```
#content-wrapper.posts-page {
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url("image path");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

(This was copied from Firebug, which is why it's not shorthand).

But had no luck. Anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem lies in that your table most likely resizes the background, so if you add this declarations, in most likely hood it should get it running just fine.

```
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-size: cover !important;
```

**Edit:**

If this doesnt work only other reason i can think of is that ios must somehow resize the body size to be as big as the content, what you have to do then is create a div inside the body tag with correct properties

```
#fixebg{
background: url(image.jpg) top;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}
```

Here is a similiar solution:

[How can I set fixed position Background image in jquery mobile for iPhone app using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923656/how-can-i-set-fixed-position-background-image-in-jquery-mobile-for-iphone-app-us)

**Edit - 2:**

*Added a fiddle you can check:*

http://jsfiddle.net/uZRXH/3/

*And here is link to try it out on your ipad:*

http://fiddle.jshell.net/uZRXH/3/show

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the full code. I edited the original post to include the full code.

Comment: @JeremyE Could u send me a link to your site, cause I made a demo and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: added a demo link to the original post. It works fine in regular browsers, but on an iPad the background scrolls.

Comment: @JeremyE Added a working example that works on both my iphone and ipad

Comment: I have tried this on iOS mobile and did not get great results with a fixed background image in regards to the image not scaling (even with background: cover). Any solutions for this?

Comment: Sorry, I worded that wrong. I have tried that solution, and although I got it working, I then had issues with scrollTop. I then found backstretch jQuery plugin that worked. Thanks for the insight as this was the closest solution I could find.

Comment: Here's a link to a fiddle with an existing background image, the one from the answer was removed: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uZRXH/140/  And also the one to view on the ipad: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uZRXH/140/show

Answer (score 7):

That website uses a trick in mobile browsers, taking advantage of the fact that while `background-attachment: fixed` doesn't work, `position: fixed` does, so in mobile browsers it just creates a `<div>` that remains fixed behind the scrolling content.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I allready build that site, the part with a fixed background would get messed up if I wrapped it in a div to give that div a fixed position. So I wrote this and it works on the iPhone.

I've got a fixed header so this was easy to use but anything that's allways at the top of the viewport will do...

```
        if (//on mobile) {
            var headerH, headerH2, viewportH, sliderH, res
            viewportH = $(window).height(),
            headerH2 = 80 //correction when measuring with fixed header,
            $topheader = $('.top_header'),
            $slider = $('#twinslider') //the element to check for if in viewport;
            function getH() {
                headerH = $topheader.offset().top;
                sliderH = $slider.offset().top;
                res = (((headerH - headerH2) - sliderH) + viewportH) / viewportH;
                if (res > 0 && res < 1.4)  {
                    return res; // thats truthy and a value for further calculation
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            getH();

            setInterval(function(){ // before i listened to scroll, but this was better for performance
                if (getH()) {//if slider is in viewport
                    $slider.find('li').css({ //the element to set the background pos for
                        'background-position': 'center ' + res * 50 + '%'
                    }, 100);

                }                   
            }, 25); 

        }
```

and then give the element to give a 'fixed background' a transition on the background-position and you're done. Not that neat though....and I feel like there's a better solution...but this works.

Answer (score 0):

1) `z-index: -1;` must be added to Breezer's second approach if you have link images otherwise the images are kept hidden (behind the background)

2) On same approach, I had to put the div before the rest of the content as follows or the page was non-scrollable if content is added inside the div tags:

`<body>
 <div id="fixedbg"></div>
 <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
 </body>`