# Fixed position background on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, background-attachment

I have a div with a background-size:cover and background-attachment:fixed. This works fine except for on iOS.

```
#featured {
    background:url(img/mountains.jpg) center bottom no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    padding-bottom:65px;
}
```

The problem is similar to these questions:
[Using background-attachment:fixed in safari on the ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011226/using-background-attachmentfixed-in-safari-on-the-ipad)
[Fixed Position Background on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009035/fixed-position-background-on-ios)

But not quite. Every solution I've found is for a fixed background on the body tag. But I need a fixed background within a div in the middle of a dynamic page. So setting a fake div to position:fixed isn't going to work for me.

Is there another way to make a fixed position background work on iOS? Do I need jQuery?

Comment: what happens on iOS? can you provide a link?

Comment: It shows the full size of the background image (not cover/contain) with normal positioning (not fixed).

Comment: Still don't want to provide a link or a fiddle so we can see the problem?  It is not possible to solve your problem with the limited info provided.